# Insert multiple row in WSO2 DSS

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am wondering if it is possible to create a webservice in WSO2 DSS based on a query like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) 
VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

I mean, I want to create a Web-Service that inserts multiple rows at once.

Is it possible to configure the input mapping for such a Web-Service?

Note: It's important to mention that the number of rows to insert is not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSO2 DSS, there is an option to enable batch requests for a data service [1]. Please look at the sample for Batch Processing [2]

I hope this helps!

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Creating+Using+Various+Data+Sources

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Batch+Processing+Sample